# mysql, find frequenties in table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in PHPMyAdmin with six columns.
In each cell there is a name.

Now I want to know in what frequencies we have each name in each column.

For example:

```
column1  column2  column3
name1    name3    name2
name1    name2    name2
name2    name3    name1
```

Then I need a list with:

```
column1           column2   column3
name1 - 2         0         1
name2 - 1         1         2
name3 - 0         2         0
```

I tried to play with:

```
SELECT Count(*) FROM aanmeldingen2013 WHERE column1 LIKE name1.
```

Can someone help me with the SQL code to generate this output?

Comment: 1. Normalize your data.

Comment: just learn [how to format](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) your post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is the most efficient method:

```
select name,
       sum(n = 1) as Column1Cnt,
       sum(n = 2) as Column1Cnt,
       sum(n = 3) as Column1Cnt
from (select (case when n.n = 1 then column1
                   when n.n = 2 then column2
                   when n.n = 3 then column3
              end) as name,
             n.n
      from t cross join
           (select 1 as n union all select 2 union all select 3) n
     ) t
```

This should be more efficient that a `union all` query because it only scans the original table once.  I've shown the example here for three columns (as in your sample data).  It should be clear how to generalize this to six columns.

Answer (score 0):

check this query

```
 SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM 'tbl_name' where column1='name1';
```